# Custom binding to change style on click not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm displaying data in a table but some of the fields are too long and cause their row to be too tall so I'm creating a custom binding that will cutoff the overflow and show the offending field with an ellipsis.

```
a, b, c, d,...
```

Then when the user clicks the field it will "unhide" the data showing all the data for that field.

My binding isn't working properly though. My goal is to initially have all the overflow hidden and to unhide each field as the user clicks the field.

My binding is doing the opposite, sort of. Initially it renders the fields *unhidden* then hides the field once the user clicks it. But once the initial click has occured the field will not toggle again.

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bflemi3/fT4dH/)

I feel like I'm over thinking this a bit...

**Update**

Once the click event is fired the value of options.data will always remain what it was initially changed to. How do I send the current version of hideOverflow as the valueAccessor to the click init function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came about because`newValueAccessor` was returning a call to `options.click` instead of returning an anonymous function that calls `options.click`. I changed this...

```
var newValueAccessor = function () {
    return options.click(!ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.data));
};
```

to this...

```
var newValueAccessor = function () {
    return function (data) {
        options.click.call(viewModel, !data.hideOverflow());
    };
};
```

and it works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You would want to toggle your `hideOverflow` observable rather than set it to the value passed into the click binding (the data itself, which is truthy).

So, you can do:

```
self.changeOverflow = function () {
    self.hideOverflow(!self.hideOverflow());
};
```

Comment: Just remember that the update binding will be triggered when the binding is first applied, which might explain why the initial state is expanded. I think the update binding shouldn't be triggered on init, because as the name implies, it should only be triggered when the associated observable is updated.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your fiddle with RP Niemeyer's solution, and my solution for your particular case.

http://jsfiddle.net/dzul1983/fT4dH/5/

I added a bang on line 15

```
options.data = !ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.data);
```

I think the update binding is a little misleading in that it's also triggered on init.